# Contents of array A changes when I sort array B, which is supposed to be a duplicate of A

Tags: arrays, sorting, kotlin, insertion-sort

I have a 10x loop to sort an array of numbers `B`(copy of original array `A`) and record the run-time, since the array gets sorted at the end of a loop i created a duplicate array `B` to be changed and use `A` to set it to it's original state at the begin of a new loop.

when it sorts `B`, `A` automatically gets sorted too even though i only send `B` .
why does this happen and how to change it?

loop:

```
for (i in 1..10) {
        val B = A
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
                val sorting = Insertion(B); sorting.sor
        }
        println(""+ cycle++ + "\t" + time)
}
```

sort:

```
class Insertion(var B: IntArray) {
    fun sort(): Unit {
        for( j in 1 until B.size){
            var key = B[j]
            var i = j-1
            while( i > -1 && B[i] > key){
                B[i+1] = B[i]
                i= i - 1
            }
            B[i+1] = key
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_`B` copy of original array `A`_" - no it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of your loop, you have an `IntArray` object, and a variable which refers to it:

```
    A ──→ IntArray
```

You then create a second variable which refers to the same `IntArray` object.

```
    A
      >─→ IntArray
    B
```

Hopefully this illustrates why changes made through the reference `B` will also be visible through the reference `A`.

If you want `B` to refer to a *different* `IntArray`, you'll have to make a copy of it, e.g.:

```
val B = A.copyOf()
```

or:

```
val B = A.clone()
```

or:

```
val B = IntArray(a.size){ A[it] }
```

or various other ways.  (`copyOf()` is usually the best.)

(Finally, please note that the Kotlin convention is for variables, methods, and properties to start with a lower-case letter, and only classes and type parameters to start with a capital.)

Comment: thank you it works perfectly, now i see that i have another issue. the time always gives me 0 in milliseconds

Comment: @PedroParreira, it's surprisingly hard to get an idea of how long code can take to run.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you use the same array. After `val B = A` `B` is a reference to array `A`, no copy was created. To create a copy you need to call `val B = A.copyOf()`.